# Undefined index when using rewriteRule in wamp

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wamp, wampserver

I have new project and I am using htaccess to rewrite the URLs. I'm sure there's nothing wrong in my code as I tested it today in xamp and on 000webhost and it worked without any problems.

But when I test the same scripts in wampServer `$_GET` isn't working on the PHP page, where I get this error:

`output is Notice: Undefined index: key in D:\wamp64\www\cp\examples.php on line 5`

The problem is with wampServer server. Maybe there is something I should change, but I do not know where the problem lies exactly.

Note: I enabled `rewrite_module` from wampServer apache module.

htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cp/
RewriteRule ^examples.html$ examples.php //it's working
RewriteRule ^examples/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ examples.php?key=$1
```

The fifth line of htaccess isn't working with PHP when using:

```
echo $_GET['key']; //output is Notice: Undefined index: key in D:\wamp64\www\cp\examples.php on line 5
```

Comment: Could you list some example URLs this is failing with please?

Comment: Thank you for your replaying bro.
i using this url
http://localhost/cp/examples/11

Comment: Bro my problem resolved by adding -MultiViews in my htaccess.
I do not know why that was working in another servers with out this option!
But anyway my problem resolved and thanks

Comment: Because your "wampServer" must be enabling `MultiViews` in the server config. By default, Apache does not enable `MultiViews`.

Comment: So can i enable it from wamp apache ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `-MultiViews` option in your code

**What is MultiViews**
A MultiViews search is where the server does an implicit filename pattern match, and choose from amongst the results.

For example, if you have a file called configuration.php (or other extension) in root folder and you set up a rule in your htaccess for a virtual folder called configuration/ then you'll have a problem with your rule because the server will choose configuration.php automatically (if MultiViews is enabled,and which is the case most of the time)
If you want to disable that behaviour, you simply have to add this in your htaccess Options -MultiViews

**Demo Example :**

use this code for
.htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cp/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^examples/(.+?)/?$ /cp/examples.php?key=$1 [L,QSA]
```

you examples.php code will be

```
<?php 
echo $_REQUEST['key'];  
?>
```

then call
http://localhost/cp/examples/27

output will be :27

Comment: "add MultiViews option" - Or rather, _disable MultiViews_.

Comment: Thank you bro MrWhite, my problem resolved. by adding that.